# Output streams in Perl: STDERR, STDOUT,

Tags: perl, unix, io

I know the output streams STDOUT and STDERR. Whenever you print to STDOUT, in a unix shell you can redirect the output like this...

```
deviolog@home:~$ perl test_script.pl > output.txt
```

or

```
deviolog@home:~$ perl test_script.pl 1> output.txt
```

When you print to STDERR, it looks the same but you switch to "channel" (?) number 2:

```
deviolog@home:~$ perl test_script.pl 2> output.txt
```

I can find in output.txt, what I was printing as error output then.

My question is, can I access "channel" number 3 somehow?
Is there something like ...

```
 print STDX "Hello World!\n";
```

... that allows a redirection like the following one?

```
deviolog@home:~$ perl test_script.pl 3> output.txt
```

p.s. A subquestion would be about the term for those "channels" ^_^

Comment: The 'channel numbers' are 'file descriptors'.

Answer (score 8):

You can create a Perl file handle for an open *file descriptor* (fd) using `open`, appending `&=` to the mode and using the file descriptor as the file name. In your case, you'd use the following:

```
open(my $fh, '>&=', 3)
```

For example,

```
$ perl -E'
   open(my $fh, ">&=", 3) or die $!;
   say fileno($fh);
   say $fh "meow";
' 3>output.txt
3

$ cat output.txt
meow
```

Comment: You see what I did there? I made cat meow. :D

Comment: Upvote  +1 for the exelent solution

Answer (score 1):

`> file` or `2> file` is called [I/O redirection](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html), those numbers such as `2` are [file descriptors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor).

In Perl, `STDIN` is standard input, corresponding to file descriptor 1, `STDOUT` and `STDOUT` corresponding to file descriptor 2 and 3, respectively. There is no `STDX` for other file descriptors. But you can use the following method to open file handles corresponding to other file descriptors (see [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)):

```
open my $fh, ">&", 3; # $fh will correspond to fd 3, for write
```

or

```
open my $fh, ">&=", 3; # $fh will correspond to fd 3, for write
```

And you need to open file descriptor 3 (for write) before you run you perl program:

```
perl script.pl 3> file
```

After that, outputs generated by statements such as `print $fh ...` will appear in `file`.

Comment: `open my $fh, ">&", 3;` will create a file handle for fd 4 (or whatever's free), after making it a copy of fd 3. (You can see this by changing `>&=` to `>&` in the code in my answer.) This is a waste.

Comment: @ikegami Yes, `>&` will call `dup`, but `>&=` will call `fdopen`. Therefore the latter is more parsimonious of file descriptors. Beside that, these two method should not have any other difference.

Comment: Will `close($fh)` be the same?

Comment: @ikegami Oh, that is another difference.

Comment: Bruh. Check the "edit queue"... Says it's "full" when some are trying to fix: `STDOUT and STDOUT corresponding to file descriptor 2 and 3`...

Answer (score 0):

No, because no OS that I know of provides a third default handle to console programs. *nix and Windows both provide stdin, stdout, and stderr (0, 1, 2). These are automatically provided to a program to allow it to take input from and write normal buffered, or abnormal unbuffered (error) output to the console.

So, as shown in other answers, you can call `open()` to open a handle and force it to fd 3, but why bother? It's non-standard, kinda pointless, and people will wonder about you.

Just use `open()` to open the file you want to write to.

Comment: Not my downvote, but...You're right about the default behaviour, but you can explicitly open a file descriptor other than {0,1,2} using notations such as `program 3> another-file`.

Comment: Yeah, you can, but why? What's the point?  You have to do something special on the command line and do something special in your program.

And whoever down-voted me, please leave a comment explaining why.